# Проблема с выводом класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть много элементов следующего вида

```
<div class="one_of_level lvl_1">
</div>

<div class="one_of_level lvl_2">
</div>

<div class="one_of_level lvl_3">
</div>
```

Вопрос: как мне получить имя второго класса при нажатии на элемент, чтоб не писать по нескольку раз hasClass и не нагружать код ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.one_of_level').click(function(){
  this.classList.forEach(item => {
    if (item.indexOf("lvl_") == 0)
      console.log(item);
  });
});
```

```css
.one_of_level {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:lightgreen;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one_of_level lvl_1">
</div>

<div class="one_of_level lvl_2">
</div>

<div class="one_of_level lvl_3">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное